# Powershell uninstall program with msiexec

Tags: powershell, java

I've run into a problem getting msiexec to remove java with Powershell.  I've output my resultant command to the screen and pasted it into a batch file and it runs great.  But when it's executed via Powershell it fails saying the "package cannot be found".  Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong? I've looked up and down google and tried a few different ways of executing the command w/o success and with the same result.

```
cls
$java = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product | where { $_.Name -like "*Java*"}
$msiexec = "c:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe";
#$msiexecargs = '/x:"$app.LocalPackage" /qr'
$msiexecargs = '/uninstall "$app.IdentifyingNumber" /qr /norestart'

if ($java -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($app in $java)
    {
        write-host $app.LocalPackage
        write-host $app.IdentifyingNumber
        #&cmd /c "msiexec /uninstall $app.IdentifyingNumber /passive"
        #Start-Process -FilePath $msiexec -Arg $msiexecargs -Wait -Passthru
        [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($msiexec, $msiexecargs);
    }
}
else { Write-Host "nothing to see here..." }
Write-Host "check end"
```

The goal is to use the Windows 7 logon script to remove all versions of Java on end-user systems and then install the latest.  I prefer to make it all Powershell, but if I can't get this working I'll just use a batch file hard coded with the uninstall GUID's

The write-host statements are all for the purpose of debugging, I'm just interested in the execution of msiexec in some variation of this format:  msiexec /x {GUID} /passive /norestart

The error I get is:
"This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

I know it works on its own, just not in this script...so I'm thinking it's a syntax thing.

If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to know the difference between this:

```
"$app.IdentifyingNumber"
```

and this

```
"$($app.IdentifyingNumber)"
```

So I think you wanted to use the latter (the code is a little bit confusing because of the commented lines):

```
&cmd /c "msiexec /uninstall $($app.IdentifyingNumber) /passive"
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I wanted to show the other things I tried in the code as well.  Where can I get more information on that modification you made? This worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: I think http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx is a good start. For more info, you would need a book like PowerShell in Action / PowerShell in Depth etc.